# Saints Row the Third DLC WARNING

Tags: xbox-360, saints-row-the-third

On xbox 360 if I join a game or someone joins my game and does not have the same DLC I get this warning message: "You are missing Downloadable Content that was previously available. Some content may be unavailable.Please re-download the content." I then have to re-install it from my DLC disk.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

it could be warning you that the other person has DLC that your disk doesn't have, i would jump onto the store and check out the list of DLC there and just see if your missing anything, it could just be something free or something that doesn't add very much to the game which was ignored when the disk was being created